# How to set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS for included directory

Tags: cmake

I have a very basic CMake project that uses Google Test.  I want to build it as a dll, and the CMakeLists.txt file in gtest indicates that `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` needs to be set in order for gtest to be built as a shared library.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` so that it shows up.  If I use cmake-gui an set the value in the cache, then I do indeed see the generated build attempt to create a dll.

Below is my CMakeLists.txt.  I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make it set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(MyProj)
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyProj main.cpp)
ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib STATIC mylib.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj MyLib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(gtest-1.7.0)
```

---

Google Test will only build as a shared library (DLL) if BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is set.  Hence I want to set that in this CmakeLists.txt file.  I know how to make my own library shared, but I can't figure out how to set that variable in a way that the gtest CMakeLists.txt file sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
 ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib STATIC mylib.cpp) // Your code STATIC lib
```

Change above line to this

```
 ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib SHARED mylib.cpp)  // Shared Lib is added
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, although all my libraries are shared. Funny thing if I run `make` second time it builds needed shared library.